# what is the difference between Hyperledger Fabric and Blockchain Platform V2.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new to blockchain and is trying to set up a blockchain network for a college project. I am confused on difference between Hyperledger Fabric and Blockchain Platform 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Blockchain Platform 2.0 is a "user managed" implementation of Hyperledger Fabric. It does have a free version, and makes deploying Fabric components easier, by providing a UI for creating and interacting with your network and components, as well as allowing users to manager their own underlying infrastructure.

I recommend, if you are just starting out, to take a look at the VS Code IBM Blockchain Platform Extension. It allows you to create a local Fabric network at the click of a button, and also allows you to create projects from templates. You'll start out with template Smart Contracts and can modify, install and test them right from VS Code. It will also allow you to download your connection profile for you local Fabric network so you can connect to your network from you applications.

[VS Code - IBM Blockchain Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform): I recommend you do the quick tutorial at this link on how to use the extension.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a managed instance of Hyperledger Fabric on IBM infrastructure.